# Evaluating $J=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^3 \ln \left(e^x+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^2}{2}+x+1\right)-x^4}{\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^2}{2}+x+1}\,dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, contest-math

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^3 ln \left(e^x+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^2}{2}+x+1\right)-x^4}{\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^2}{2}+x+1}\,dx$$

My attempts:

I wanted to make sure if this integral exists, ran this through Wolfram, check [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5B%5Cfrac%5C%28123%29Power%5Bx%2C3%5D+ln+%5Cleft%5C%2840%29Power%5Be%2Cx%5D%2B%5Cfrac%5C%28123%29Power%5Bx%2C3%5D%5C%28125%29%5C%28123%296%5C%28125%29%2B%5Cfrac%5C%28123%29Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%5C%28125%29%5C%28123%292%5C%28125%29%2Bx%2B1%5Cright%5C%2841%29-Power%5Bx%2C4%5D%5C%28125%29%5C%28123%29%5Cfrac%5C%28123%29Power%5Bx%2C3%5D%5C%28125%29%5C%28123%296%5C%28125%29%2B%5Cfrac%5C%28123%29Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%5C%28125%29%5C%28123%292%5C%28125%29%2Bx%2B1%5C%28125%29%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C%E2%88%9E%7D%5D);

$$J=4.9348$$

Tried some rudimentary techniques;

$$J=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^3 ln \left(e^x+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^2}{2}+x+1\right)}{\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^2}{2}+x+1}\,dx-\int_0^{\infty}\frac{6x^4}{x^3+3x^2+6x+6}\,dx$$

The second integral was not convergent, so this attempt failed.

Tried multiple substitutions and trying to match along generalized forms, but that did not help either.

The last attempt includes;

Rewriting the integral; $$p(x)=\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^2}{2}+x+1=\sum_{r=0}^{3}\frac{x^r}{r!}$$

$$J=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^3 ln \left(e^x+p(x)\right)-x^4}{p(x)}\,dx$$

I am stuck here and am interested in learning how to carry this forward.

Edit : Found this integral's value to be $\frac{\pi^2}{2}$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can rewrite the integral as

$$J = \int_0^\infty \frac{x^3\log\left(1+\left(\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^2}{2}+x+1\right)e^{-x}\right)}{\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^2}{2}+x+1}dx$$

by factoring out the $e^x$ from the log. Now denote

$$J[a] = \int_0^\infty \frac{x^3\log\left(1+a\left(\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^2}{2}+x+1\right)e^{-x}\right)}{\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^2}{2}+x+1}dx$$

and consider

$$J'[a] = \int_0^\infty \frac{x^3e^{-x}}{1+a\left(\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^2}{2}+x+1\right)e^{-x}}dx $$

$$ = -\frac{6}{a}\int_0^\infty \frac{a\left(\frac{x^2}{2}+x+1\right)e^{-x}-a\left(\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^2}{2}+x+1\right)e^{-x}}{1+a\left(\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^2}{2}+x+1\right)e^{-x}}dx$$

$$= -\frac{6}{a}\log\left(1+a\left(\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^2}{2}+x+1\right)e^{-x}\right)\Biggr|_0^\infty = \frac{6\log(1+a)}{a}$$

From the original integral we know that $J[0] = 0$, so the answer we want is

$$J[1] = 6\int_0^1\frac{\log(1+a)}{a}da = \boxed{\frac{\pi^2}{2}}$$

Comment: Wonderful! Could you share about the intuition behind the position of the parameter 'a'

Comment: @ayan it canceled out the denominator

Comment: Thank you very much..

Answer (score 7):

*Since @Ninad Munshi already gave the nice, elegant and more than efficient solution, I made the problem more genaral;*

$$I_n=\int_0^\infty \frac {x^n \log\Big(e^x +\sum_{r=0}^{n}\frac{x^r}{r!}  \Big)-x^{n+1} } {\sum_{r=0}^{n}\frac{x^r}{r!} }\,dx$$

If you make the problem more general assuming that the polynomial part is the beginning of the series of $e^x$ to $O(x^{n+1})$, using
$$\sum_{r=0}^{n}\frac{x^r}{r!}=\frac{e^x\,\, \Gamma (n+1,x)}{n!}$$ to face with $a=1$
$$I_n=n! \int_0^\infty x^n \,e^{-x}\,\frac{\log \left(1+a\,\frac{\Gamma (n+1,x)}{n!}\right)}{\Gamma (n+1,x)}\,dx$$

Differentiating with respect to $a$
$$I'_n=n! \,\frac{ (\log ((a+1) \Gamma (n+1))-\log (\Gamma (n+1)))}{a}$$
$$I_n=\int_0^1 I'_n\,da=\frac{\pi ^2 }{12} \,n!$$

Answer (score 3):

**@Ninad Munshi** gave us a decent solution while **@Claude Leibovici** generalised it using Gamma function. I am now trying to use Ninad Munshi’s method to generalise as @Claude’s.
$$
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^n \ln \left(e^x+\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k !}\right)-x^{n+1}}{\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k ! }} d x= \frac{n !}{12} \pi^2
$$
Proof:

Let $p_n(x)= \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k !}$, then $$\frac{x^n}{n!}=p_n(x)-p_{n-1}(x )=p_n(x)-p’_n(x) \tag*{(*)}  $$
Now consider the parametric integral
$$
I(a)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^n \ln \left(e^x+a p_n(x)\right)-x^{n+1}}{p_n(x)} d x
$$
Differentiating $I(a)$ w.r.t. $a$ yields
$$
I^{\prime}(a) =\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{e^x+a p_n(x)} d x 
=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x} x^n}{1+a e^{-x} p_n(x)} d x
$$
Using $(*)$, we have

\begin{aligned}
I^{\prime}(a) & =n ! \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x}\left(p _n(x)-p_n^{\prime}(x)\right)}{1+a e^{-x} p_n} d x \\
& =-\frac{n !}{a} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{d\left(a e^{-x} p_n(x)\right)}{1+a e^{-x} p_n(x)} \\
& =-\frac{n !}{a}\left[\ln \left(1+a e^{-x} p_n(x)\right]_0^{\infty}\right. \\
& =\frac{n !}{a} \ln (1+a)
\end{aligned}
Integrating w.r.t. $a$ from $0$ to $1$ concludes that
$$
\boxed{I(1)=I(1)-I(0) =n! \int_0^1 \frac{\ln (1+a)}{a} d a =\frac{n !}{12} \pi^2}
$$